# Jquery Custom alert box

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok this is the issues. I have 2 types of alert box one for success and another for error. Currently i have zend based application, these alert box will shows up whenever users fill up a form such as profile updates, new submissions etc. Now what i need to know is, how can i custom made name of class for each alert box so that if errors occurs Jquery will add a class to alert box and display the box? Following are my 2 alert box

Success:

```
 <div id="alert-container">
        <div class="info-alert alert-box-success">
            <p class="info-alert-text">
              // message will be custom added by jquery
            </p>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Error:

```
<div id="alert-container">
 <div class="info-alert alert-box-error">
  <p class="info-alert-text">
    // message will be custom added by jquery
  </p>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how i currently use Jquery to process user submissions:

```
$("#send2friends_submit").on("click", function(){


              $('.share-event').attr('disabled',true);
              $('.share-event').addClass('ybtn-disabled');
                var f_mail = $.trim($('textarea#emails').val());
                var f_msg = $.trim($('textarea#emails-note').val());
                var f_eid = $('#eid').val();
                if(f_mail == '' || !validateEmail(f_mail)){
                $('.info-alert').show();
                $('#send2friends_submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#send2friends_submit').removeClass('ybtn-disabled');

                return ;
              }
              if(f_msg == ''){
                $('.info-alert').show();
                $('#send2friends_submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#send2friends_submit').removeClass('ybtn-disabled');

                return ;
              }
});
```

The question is, how can i add 1 generic alert box for each page so that if error is encounter `alert-box-error` will display and if success is `alert-box-success` will be display with custom message? Currently only error message are shows up if i made `info-alert` display as block. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before showing `.info-alert` you add the content and the correct class, it would look something like this:

```
$('.info-alert')
.removeClass('alert-box-error')
.addClass('alert-box-success')
.find('p')
.text('This is a success message')
```

And obviously viceversa for the error.

Basically what you do is first removing the class you don't need, then adding the class you are looking for to the container. The you look for the contained `<p>` and edit its message text accordingly.

[**Here is a working demo for you**](http://jsbin.com/urakem/2)

You got success and error messages **using just one generic `alert` element**.